# SharePoint 2010 Announcement web part - truncate/char limit issue

Tags: 2010, splistitem, upgrade

There are old threads on this topic but most of them for MOSS or prior versions or without any resolutions. [This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sharepoint2010general/thread/88071e17-49ca-4ea9-ae38-584cf0bdf6c6) is close but solution doesn't work for me. Feel free to forward any working link.

We upgraded from MOSS 2007 to SP 2010. We are using Announcement web part with much large Announcement text (tables etc.) which exceeds allowed size (250 char I think). Right now text truncates with "..."

I tried below:

1. Edit Web part from SP Designer 2010 - apparently this was the solution in 2007 but there is no way to do it in 2010.
2. Edit file C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\AnnouncementsList\Announce\schema.xml
3. Edit Announcement List Settings -> Edit Title: change maximum number of characters. Error: Maximum number of characters must be between 1 and 255.
4. No appropriate Web part property.

Is there any working solution to this problem for SP 2010 SP1?  Thank you !!!

[Cross post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/1509f57f-e8b3-4e1e-b0d1-ed2be3203b5d) but no helpful response so far.

Comment: @casperOne - Is this new thing? I see gazillion similar questions on SO with answers. This may need programming fix. Thank you!

Comment: Your question shows no original research and just links to external resources.  I'd migrate it, but it doesn't meet quality standards for the destination site either.

Comment: Yes there was lot of work done. Unfortunately no success. I'll post details later today.

Comment: Can you open this question now? I've added more details to it. Thanks!

Comment: I see undownvote but this is still closed as off topic?? I hope that we can open this question and get some responses. I hope this bad SO experience is limited to this question.